# issue for vulnerability library FinestWebView-Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I am working with [this library](https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android) , but Google is sending a vulnerability regarding the library

This is the message:

> FinestWebViewActivity$MyWebViewClient->shouldOverrideUrlLoading

and I also received [this link with information](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9101196?hl=es-419)!

Would I have to set `android: usesCleartextTraffic` in the Manifest  to
`false`?

I would appreciate help!

Comment: Avoid using that library. That may steal your app sensitive data